# "OSError: FS_Info_Con: (tsk3.cpp:214) Unable to open the image as a filesystem" in Python3 using the pytsk3 library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to search on google and also checked for any possible solutions here but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
partition_choice = int(input("\nEnter the number of the partition you want to examine (or * for all partitions): "))

if partition_choice == '*':
    partitions_to_process = volume_info
else:
    partitions_to_process = partition_choice

file_system = pytsk3.TSK_FS_TYPE_DETECT(image_name)

directory = file_system.open_dir(path='/')
```

When I run this code and I choose the partition number, I am getting the following error:

```
file_system = pytsk3.TSK_FS_TYPE_DETECT(image_file)                
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I am asking the user to either select a partition or all partitions and once the user has inputted either a number or an *, the code should proceed to detect the type of file system from the image ("image.raw").

**Edit:**

I changed the following "file_system = pytsk3.TSK_FS_TYPE_DETECT(image_name)" to this:

```
file_system = pytsk3.FS_Info(image_name)
```

But I still got an error:

```
file_system = pytsk3.FS_Info(image_name)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: FS_Info_Con: (tsk3.cpp:214) Unable to open the image as a filesystem at offset: 0x00000000 with error: Cannot determine file system type
```

I tried looking up this error on google but found nothing on how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This suggests that `TSK_FS_TYPE_DETECT` is an integer constant, not a callable function. Are you following a tutorial or something that told you to use it like this?

Comment: As the error message clearly says, `pytsk3.TSK_FS_TYPE_DETECT` is an integer. If it wasn't supposed to be an int, check your code, you probably did something like `pytsk3.TSK_FS_TYPE_DETECT = 7` before. But without knowing the library, if it respects Python's conventions, it probably is a constant (because they should be written in uppercase), so it probably is an int rather than a function...

Comment: I don't know this library, but just googling (https://code.google.com/archive/p/aff4/wikis/TSKPythonBnding.wiki) it looks like `file_system = pytsk3.FS_Info(image_name)` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: No I am not using any tutorials, I took it from its wording to detect the type of filesystem isn't that what's supposed to do? Forgot to mention that I am using the pytsk3 library.

Comment: @slothrop - I had tried file_system = pytsk3.FS_Info(image_name) but I get the following error:

"file_system = pytsk3.FS_Info(image_name)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: FS_Info_Con: (tsk3.cpp:214) Unable to open the image as a filesystem at offset: 0x00000000 with error: Cannot determine file system type"

I have looked for that error on google but found nothing.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - The code should be as slothrop mentioned which it should be like this: "file_system = pytsk3.FS_Info(image_name)"

Comment: Ah, sorry. Maybe edit your question and title to reflect the error you receive now, so that people can see it's a pytsk3 question and hopefully someone who knows the lib will see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to submit as a comment, but not going to sign up to do it.

When your choice is *, run a for loop through your volume_info (which I'm assuming is pytsk3.Volume_Info). If the volume has the flag pytsk3.TSK_VS_PART_FLAG_META or pytsk3.TSK_VS_PART_FLAG_UNALLOC, continue to the next volume.

Good luck